# modal doesn't show when placed inside a div that has a show/hide function

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, show-hide

I have a straightforward multi-image modal set up which works perfectly. However, the page I am trying to integrate it on is set up as follows: I have a header, a set of links to the left, and a main section next to the links. When a link is clicked it changes the content of the main section through a hide/show function. In this manner all of the site is on one page. The problem is that when I place the modal inside the hidden div of choice, the images show up when the main contents is changed, but the modal does not open when the image is clicked. Here is the code for the main div and the hidden div where the modal will be (the user needs to click on where the image would be that says "fall bill" to open the div where the modal is. You will see that I placed some images in as holders. The images fade when hovered as they are supposed to. I cannot figure out any reason why the modal will not show up in such an instance but works if it is not inside a div that can be hidden.

Here is a the code:

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var images = document.getElementsByClassName('img');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");

for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  var img = images[i];
  img.onclick = function(evt) {
    console.log(evt);
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
  }
}

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}


function show(param_div_id) {
  document.getElementById('main').innerHTML = document.getElementById(param_div_id).innerHTML;
}
```

```css
.img {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.img:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 10;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}

.modal-content,
#caption {
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .modal-content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

#main {
  background-image: url('bkgd.jpg');
  display: block;
  width: 690px;
  font-family: "Book Antiqua";
  color: #004B97;
  font-size: 16pt;
  padding: 2%;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: medium #9999FF solid;
}

.mainContents {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 690px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

#home,
#bills,
#munTax,
#schoolTax,
#interimTax,
#taxCert,
#dupsReceipts,
#directions,
#FAQ {
  display: none;
  width: 300px;
  font-family: "Book Antiqua";
  color: #004B97;
}

.head {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 16pt;
  color: #004B97;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.head2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 14pt;
  color: #835BF9;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.lower {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto auto 10;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 10px;
  align-items: center;
}

.pay {
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url('background.jpg');
  color: #0D095E;
  font-size: 14pt;
  border: medium #9999FF solid;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="mainContents">
    <div class="head">Outside Receiving Hours:<br/> Please use secure drop box outside building
    </div>
    <div class="head2">
      <strong>2022 Millage Rates</strong><br/> County - 3.2273; Township - .62; PVSD (School + Library) = 23.8117
    </div>
    <div class="lower">
      <div class="pay">
        Pay Tax Bill Online<br/>
        <img alt="Pay Online" height="80" src="payonline.png" width="144">
      </div>

      <div class="pay">
        Understanding Your Tax Bill<br/>

        <button onclick="show('bills')" class="link"><img alt="Fall Bill" height="129" src="FallTaxBill-psd.png" width="300"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="bills">
  <div class="mainContents">
    <div class="head">Understanding Your Tax Bill</div><br/>
    <div class="lower">
      <div class="pay">
        Spring Tax Bill<br/>
        <img class="img" src="http://onebigphoto.com/uploads/2012/10/midnight-sun-in-lofoten-norway.jpg" alt="Midnight sun in Lofoten, Norway" width="300" height="200">
      </div>
      <div class="pay">
        Fall Tax Bill<br/>
        <img class="img" src="http://cdn-image.travelandleisure.com/sites/default/files/styles/1600x1000/public/1490029386/fisherman-cabin-hamnoy-lofoten-islands-norway-NORWAY0320.jpg?itok=cpPuUjh1" alt="Fishermen's cabins in Lofoten, Norway" width="300" height="200">
      </div>
      <div class="pay">
        Fall Tax Bill Stubs<br/>
        <img class="img" src="http://fjordtours.blob.core.windows.net/fjordtours-umbraco/1199/gerirangerfjord-per-ottar-walderhaug-fjordnorway.jpg" alt="Gerirangerfjord, Norway" width="300" height="200">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the listeners are removed when content is swapped, add image listeners there instead:

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var images = document.getElementsByClassName('img');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");


var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}


function show(param_div_id) {
  document.getElementById('main').innerHTML = document.getElementById(param_div_id).innerHTML;

    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
      var img = images[i];
      img.onclick = function(evt) {
        console.log(evt);
        modal.style.display = "block";
        modalImg.src = this.src;
      }
    }

}
```

```css
.img {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.img:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 10;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}

.modal-content,
#caption {
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .modal-content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

#main {
  background-image: url('bkgd.jpg');
  display: block;
  width: 690px;
  font-family: "Book Antiqua";
  color: #004B97;
  font-size: 16pt;
  padding: 2%;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: medium #9999FF solid;
}

.mainContents {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 690px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

#home,
#bills,
#munTax,
#schoolTax,
#interimTax,
#taxCert,
#dupsReceipts,
#directions,
#FAQ {
  display: none;
  width: 300px;
  font-family: "Book Antiqua";
  color: #004B97;
}

.head {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 16pt;
  color: #004B97;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.head2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 14pt;
  color: #835BF9;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.lower {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto auto 10;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 10px;
  align-items: center;
}

.pay {
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url('background.jpg');
  color: #0D095E;
  font-size: 14pt;
  border: medium #9999FF solid;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="mainContents">
    <div class="head">Outside Receiving Hours:<br/> Please use secure drop box outside building
    </div>
    <div class="head2">
      <strong>2022 Millage Rates</strong><br/> County - 3.2273; Township - .62; PVSD (School + Library) = 23.8117
    </div>
    <div class="lower">
      <div class="pay">
        Pay Tax Bill Online<br/>
        <img alt="Pay Online" height="80" src="payonline.png" width="144">
      </div>

      <div class="pay">
        Understanding Your Tax Bill<br/>

        <button onclick="show('bills')" class="link"><img alt="Fall Bill" height="129" src="FallTaxBill-psd.png" width="300"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="bills">
  <div class="mainContents">
    <div class="head">Understanding Your Tax Bill</div><br/>
    <div class="lower">
      <div class="pay">
        Spring Tax Bill<br/>
        <img class="img" src="http://onebigphoto.com/uploads/2012/10/midnight-sun-in-lofoten-norway.jpg" alt="Midnight sun in Lofoten, Norway" width="300" height="200">
      </div>
      <div class="pay">
        Fall Tax Bill<br/>
        <img class="img" src="http://cdn-image.travelandleisure.com/sites/default/files/styles/1600x1000/public/1490029386/fisherman-cabin-hamnoy-lofoten-islands-norway-NORWAY0320.jpg?itok=cpPuUjh1" alt="Fishermen's cabins in Lofoten, Norway" width="300" height="200">
      </div>
      <div class="pay">
        Fall Tax Bill Stubs<br/>
        <img class="img" src="http://fjordtours.blob.core.windows.net/fjordtours-umbraco/1199/gerirangerfjord-per-ottar-walderhaug-fjordnorway.jpg" alt="Gerirangerfjord, Norway" width="300" height="200">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly now. Such a simple solution - I just couldn't figure it out.